# Mega Dropdown with Bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, submenu

I need mega drop down menu like:

https://codyhouse.co/demo/mega-dropdown/index.html

But by using Bootstrap and jQuery.

Please check small devices.

Note:Now I am using bootstrap-v4 and I want to show toggle menu like mobile in https://codyhouse.co/demo/mega-dropdown/index.html

Comment: Tell us what you have already tried

Comment: I can use codyhouse mega menu but the size of this menu is too high.